Fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS boots into a white screen
The problem I am facing
I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 on an external SSD and want to boot it on my Windows PC. The problem I am facing is that in normal boot, it always arrives at a white screen with the error message:

Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator.

White screen error image
What I tried
Reinstalling gdm3
Unfortunately, I am my own system administrator. I found that the system boots normally in recovery mode. After viewing several posts on similar issues, I deduced it is a problem with gdm3.
Hence, I uninstalled and reinstalled gdm3. It resolves the problem, but only for one time. If I reboot, the white screen resumes. This is what I did:
First I boot through recovery mode. Then in the terminal:
sudo apt purge gdm3
sudo reboot

After reboot, in the CLI I do:
sudo apt install gdm3
sudo service gdm start

This takes me to the login screen, but if I reboot, the white screen error comes back. This time sudo service gdm start does not start the login screen. If I use systemctl status gdm, it shows gdm is running normally.
Switching to lightdm
I have also tried to switch to lightdm, it leads to a different white screen error that says:

Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again.

Of course, the log out button does nothing.
Reinstalling Nvidia driver
If I enter the terminal at the white screen by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3, sometimes these error messages show up.
Nvidia error image
So the problem could be with the Nvidia drivers. My GPU is a Nvidia 1660 Ti. I let the Ubuntu installer handled installing the drivers during system installation. I tried to remove those drivers with
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo apt --purge remove '*nvidia*535*'
sudo apt autoremove

Then reinstall following the official guide with
sudo ubuntu-drivers install

It did not resolve the problem. I have tried other methods for installing Nvidia drivers like in this post with
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535 nvidia-dkms-535

Of course I tried this method after removing the drivers installed via the first method. I have also tried to use the Additional Drivers app to install the driver, but I do not think reinstalling the driver made a difference. The white screen shows up anyway.
Reinstalling gnome desktop
I also tried to install gnome desktop following this post.
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt install gnome-shell gnome

Did not resolve the issue.
What I want to know
To summarize, the white screen does not provide any reason as to why the error happens, which is very absurd. The only solution, although one-time, is to reinstall gdm3. There are error messages associated with the Nvidia driver, but reinstalling the driver does not fix the problem.
I want to ask how I can identify the source of the problem and resolve it. Is this clear enough, community bot?
Investigations
Uninstall Nvidia drivers and don't install them
Uninstalled the drivers using
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo apt --purge remove '*nvidia*535*'
sudo apt autoremove

Only remaining packages after searching with dpkg -l | grep 'nvidia' are firmware-nvidia-graphics and linux-signatures-nvidia-6.8.0-40-generic.
Rebooted and still encountered the white screen.
Boot from a usb drive
I should also add, when I etched the mirror image onto the usb drive and booted it to install Ubuntu, choosing Try or Install Ubuntu led to the same white screen. Only Ubuntu (Safe Graphics) boots successfully and let me install Ubuntu on my SSD.
However, the same usb stick with Ubuntu 22.04 etched can boot into Ubuntu normally without needing to use safe graphics. Maybe I should just install 22.04 instead?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What happens if you uninstall the Nvidia drivers and do not install them at all?

@user68186 It still boots into the white screen. I will add the details in the question

What is your hardware? Check the vendors of hardware (motherboard/ssd) for any available firmware updates.  In recovery, try the apt update/apt upgrade -- then you might be offered later Nvidia drivers than 535. Adding the repository graphics-drivers PPA will get you the 555 driver, but you didn't mention what nvidia hardware you have, so that might not be appropriate.

@ubfan1 I have a ROG Strix G731GU laptop with Intel 9750H, Intel UHD Graphics 630, and Nvidia 1660 Ti. 535 is the latest when I do sudo ubuntu-drivers list.

@ubfan1 Just checked. The BIOS is the latest for my laptop.

Solution found: install Ubuntu 22.04
I concluded that if the system cannot even normally boot from a bootable USB, there must be something really incompatible with it. I resorted to installing Ubuntu 22.04. It works out of the box.
Something else
However, the caveat is that the Ubuntu 22.04 installer installs GRUB to my Windows drive even though I chose my external SSD to install the bootloader. This is a known bug with the installer. If someone encounters the same issue, the solution is to use boot-repair to install GRUB to your Ubuntu drive. Then delete the GRUB in the Windows drive, or just leave it be. You can follow the instructions here, or mount that partition in Ubuntu using the Disks app and do the same thing.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.
There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments. Another problem is that your host system probably will not boot without the external device (since needed grub files are on it).

@ubfan1 I only reinstalled the GRUB files for ubuntu and did not touch the windows part. Luckily the file system was straightforward. One folder for ubuntu and another for windows. My windows still works after I pulled out my external drive.
